# Managed or manual written schema.xml for the nested json object in Solr 7.5

Tags: solr

Here is nested json object have to save in SOLR then retrive it as is and ability to query on any level of attribute -

```
{
    "number": "19940852773",

    "details": [{
            "number": "19940852773",
            "pId": 70972062,
            "bReviewReduction": 66.7000
        },
        {
            "number": "19940852773",
            "pId": 70972063,
            "bReviewReduction": 0.0000
        }
    ],

    "line_details": [{
            "number": "19940852773",
            "paymentId": 70972062,
            "paymentDetailId": 14972918
        },
        {
            "number": "19940852773",
            "paymentId": 70972905,
            "paymentDetailId": 14973428

        },
        {
            "number": "19940852773",
            "paymentId": 70972905,
            "paymentDetailId": 14973429,
            "numOfServiceLines": 21
        }
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr doesn't support indexing the content as-is, but you can [use the custom JSON indexing features](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-and-indexing-custom-json.html#transforming-and-indexing-custom-json) to transform it to a form. Submitting the document above will give you a document / set of documents containing a number of childDocument entries, and you'll have to handle this through the child/parent transformations when retrieving and querying.

Usually it's a better strategy to try to flatten the document structure into something suitable for answering the queries you want Solr to answer for you, instead of trying to keep the raw data structure and special case all queries to handle that.